# How do I display a web page in my app, in a way that it does not take the user out of the app itself?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to display a webpage in my app using dart. How would I do this, so that the user isn't directed out of the app but views it in a way similar to webview for android?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=webview

Comment: ...could you use an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webview plugin: 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin
Or
URL luncher:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher

Comment: Keep in mind that's just a developer preview and is missing a lot of functionality.